# What does a typical compact set in $\Bbb C^n$ look like?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

So, what I can think of is that if $\Bbb C^n$ is considered a vector space over $\Bbb R$, then it is just isomorphic to $\Bbb R^{2n}$ and then sets closed and bounded in $\Bbb R^{2n}$ characterize compact sets therein. But what if it is considered a vector space over $\Bbb C$? Also, is there some other way to look at compact sets in $\Bbb C^n$ taken over $\Bbb R$? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What topology are you referring to?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}^n$ over $\mathbb{C}$ is of dimension $n$ (just consider standard orthogonal basis $(1,0,\dots,0),(0,1,0,\dots,0)$ etc) so it must be isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ over $\mathbb{R}$. Assuming metric topology on both spaces this isomorphism is automatically an homeomorphism, so again compact sets are closed bounded ones

Comment: @user160738 alright, so then $A=\{(z_1,z_2,z_3) : z_1^2+z_2^2+z_3^2=1\}$  is compact in $\Bbb C^n$ over $\Bbb C$, right? But what about over $\Bbb R$?

Comment: What do you mean by 'compact over $\mathbb{C}$'?

Comment: When it's taken as a vector space over $\Bbb C$

Comment: @user160738 I don't understand what you are referring to as "being isomorphic over $\Bbb R$", but $\Bbb C^n$ is undoubtedly a $\Bbb R$-vector space of dimension $2n$ and, topologically, it is **not** homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^{n}$. It is homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^{2n}$.

Comment: The vector space structure is a bit of a red herring here. The open sets are what are relevant.

Comment: @copper.hat but the open sets would change with a change of field right?

Comment: There is an isometry between $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ (with the usual topologies), so the open (and hence compact) sets are the same. The vector space structure is irrelevant unless you want some other topology. All that matters from the current perspective is the distance.

Comment: Dear @DeepishaSolanki: Compactness is defined in terms of open sets,so if the spaces have 'same' open sets then compact sets are 'same'.

Comment: To put it another way :-).

Comment: @ArpitKansal I get that, thanks but then let me ask this: does $\Bbb C^n$ have the same topology when considered as a vector space over $\Bbb C$ and $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @DeepishaSolanki: Also note that for any $z_1,z_2 \in \mathbb C, z_1^2+z_2^2+z=1$ has solution hence A is ... (See the comment of copper.hat related with isometry)

Comment: @ArpitKansal you would need $z^2$ there wouldn't you?

Comment: @DeepishaSolanki: I think you're confused because probably you're think for instance your set $A$ as unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$ for suitable $n$.Note that unit ball in $\mathbb C^n$ is different from the corresponding ball in $\mathbb R^{2n}$ mainly because $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed. Also you may note that $(a,ai,1) \in A$ for any $a$ ,hence $A$ is again ..

Comment: How would you define the distance between two points in the two spaces you are considering? What does the field have to do with it?

Comment: @copper.hat just the Euclidean distance

Comment: What I'm saying is the the choice of field does not impact the distance. The choice of $\mathbb{R}$ vs. $\mathbb{C}$ just affects scalar multiplication which is not relevant here.

Comment: @DeepishaSolanki: Does not really matter.  Think of $z_1^2+z_2^2+z^2=1$ as a polynomial in $z$ and recall $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed.

Comment: Think about how you define open sets in either context, that is all that matters here. The two spaces are different, but the open sets are the same.

Comment: @ArpitKansal okay, I think I get it, then $A$ would be unbounded and effectively cannot be compact, yes?

Comment: Yeah perfect.Please do note that $A$ is not unit ball in $\mathbb C^3$,unit ball is defined as $|z_1|^2 + |z_2|^2 + |z_3|^2 = 1$. The only thing which matters here is topology i.e. open sets as copper.hat pointed out.

Comment: Right! thanks very much both of you!